# Is there any way to prevent access to text files other than encryption?

Tags: c++

Basically I am implementing a dictionary and I dont want any user to access my dictionary .txt file. I need to access the file from my program. The txt files are too large that encryption method takes a lot of time to decrypt them. What other methods are there ?

Comment: encryption doesn't stop users from accessing your dictionary, it just makes it harder to read.. so, the question is, are you trying to completly deny access to the file or just make it non human readable ?

Comment: Would you like to prevent users from reading *and* writing, or only from writing to the file?

Comment: Your best option would be to store all data on a server, and request items from the dictionary ad-hoc. You may implement this as a web-service and control number and frequency of requests from every client and/or IP-address.

Comment: If someone really wants to read your encrypted file, she will read it no matter what you do to protect the file: if your program can read it, a sufficiently determined human will read it too; it's just a law of nature, there's nothing you can do about it.

Comment: yes i wan completely deny access to other user ...t

Comment: i just wat that the user should not be able to read the file file but my program can ...

Comment: I just want them not to use or not to read my file encryption is one option but i doesnt suits me in ma case ...

Comment: What OS/hardware are you using? "hiding" the file may be an option, but requires some OS-specific functionality, and will be "beatable" by someone with admin privileges.

Comment: i dont want to hide them just want the user not to read them ...

Comment: If your program and your user are different user-id's, then use your OS file permissions to block access.

Comment: How big are those files (in bytes)? It feels strange that a dictionary text file is so big that encryption isn't a viable option. Anyhow, as other said, if your program can read it then the user can read it, there's no escape from this, you can only make this more difficult.

Answer (score 2):

You have set yourself a nearly impossible task.

By some definitions of "read", any user of your program can "read" the file, just by asking the program to make a lookup.

If you want to prevent read access to the file by other means than your program, your only effective option will be to deny physical access to the file (by hosting it on a server and have an API in front of it that only allows queries). Any knowledgeable and determined user with access to both the program and the data file will be able to decipher it.
Encrypting the data file can make this much harder for some people, but only if the key is not built into the program, but users have to enter it manually. Then only those with the key have a reasonable chance of deciphering the data file.

Answer (score 1):

Bart's answer is completely valid. But the problem could have a solution.

Depending what the dictionary actually does, you might be able to use a Bloom filter or other probabilistic hash data structure to avoid storing its contents in any direct fashion whatsoever. But you wouldn't be able to access the words in that case, only to check whether a word is there or not.

Such a dictionary would still be vulnerable to attack by querying the program for all possible words. That could be feasible or not; it's unclear what you're really doing.

Answer (score 0):

If you REALLY take the security seriuous, then you should use proper, long key, encryption. [But see comments about "where do you store teh key" - you can't do this safely].

However, if you simply want the file to be a little difficult to read in a text editor, you could use some form of simple compression [with the added benefit of it taking less space]. Bytepair encoding is every simple to implement. Huffman coding is a little more effort. Obviouslky using an existing encoding technique, such as gzip, bzip2, xz or some such would be somewhat less difficult for someone to break, so won't have the same protective properties.

If the purpose is to make it hard for REGULAR users (e.g. people who are not well versed in cracking codes and breaking into software) then storing the keys with a simple "bit-twiddling" - for examply take the top and bottom 4 bits of the character and reverse them: `char ch = (orig_ch >> 4) | ((orig_ch & (1<<4)-1) << 4);` would make the content pretty much unreadable for ordinary users.

Comment: Cant i block the user of my software to not even red them using any saftware installer file access properties etc or any other way around .. I mentioned ei dont want to encrypt  :(

Comment: There is no way that you can, in a way that isn't fairly easy for someone with admin rights on the machine, to bypass/override. E.g. you can put the file as "hidden" in Windows, but if you give the right switches to "attrib" or set Windows Explorer to the right settings, the file will be visible. Same applies in Linux if someone can get root access, they can change the file. Further, if your application is supposed to read the file and execute in the user's name [and not executing in the user's name will make you unpopular with admin], the file must be readable in the user's privileges.

Comment: And there is a big difference between "don't make it every easy to read" and "you have to prevent the national security from being compromised". The former can be achieved with VERY lightweight processing of the data, the latter requires proper encryption. Please explain which of these you are trying to achieve.

Comment: `you should use proper, long key, encryption` - where will you store the key?

Comment: Hopefully not anywhere the user can get at it... Fetch it from a server somewhere, perhaps, using SSL?

Comment: Your client side SSL certificate's private key will be accessible to the user because he has the same file permissions as your program. So using SSL is useless.

Comment: So, if it's "national security" level, then you wouldn't store it on the local computer, encrypted or otherwise. If it's "make it sufficiently complex that most ordinary people give up before finding the key [not counting FBI, CIA and KGB, etc]" then I'm sure encrypting it would work. But if the key and the encrypted data are ever in the same place, you can't really fix that.

Comment: you cannot hide it from the user - even if you REALLY take security seriously and use proper, long key, encryption.

Comment: I agree. But you can make it more difficult to get, if it's only present for a brief period of time.

Answer (score 0):

Like many people already observed, its not possible to secure your data from users 100% of the time. Any sufficiently determined user will get to it, given enough time.

However, there is a "simple" way to make sure that the user doesn't "mess" with the data in your dictionary file: you could use binary file I/O:

```
ofstream out("dictionary.dat",ios::binary);
out.write((char*) &your_data, sizeof(your_data));
```

And for reading, you do something similar:

```
ifstream in("dictionary.dat",ios::binary);
in.read((char*) &your_data, sizeof(your_data));
```

This isn't "encryption" in true sense of the word, its just an alternative representation that makes it harder for people to "mess" with your data.

Also, rather than worrying about *if* users will mess with your data files, it would make more sense to implement methods of detecting if the file has been tampered (eg: checksums, file hashes etc.) and refusing to load it.